# How do I install/use Android Studio on an mSD Card?

Tags: java, android

I've got a a tablet running windows 10 full.  Unfortunately it has a very small amount of memory and I wanted to install Android Studio on an SD card but I wasn't sure if you could do that.  If you can, does my Java folder need to be installed on to the micro SD card as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't install Android Studio to a non local disk.

And Java can be installed anywhere as long as the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and java is in your PATH.

Also, it is worth mentioning that you'll need even more space to download the Android SDK to actually program anything. That's another several hundred MB